# PYthon: How does this code work?

Tags: python

```
def color(self):
    name_hash = hash(self.name)

    red = name_hash & 0xFF          # What is this sort of operation? 
    green = (name_hash << 0xFF) & 0xFF            # What does 0xFF used for?
    blue = (name_hash << 0xFFFF) & 0xFF

    make_light_color = lambda x: x / 3 + 0xAA     # Why plux 0xAA?

    red = make_light_color(red)
    green = make_light_color(green)
    blue = make_light_color(blue)

    return 'rgb(%s,%s,%s)' % (red, green, blue)
```

Comment: I don't think `(name_hash << 0xFF)` makes any sense. Where did you get  this code from?

Comment: This code *doesn't* work.  `name_hash << 0xFF` is surely a mistake, perhaps intended to be `name_hash >> 8` and likewise `name_hash << 0xFFFF` is perhaps intended to be `name_hash >> 16`.  See the links for the meaning of [`&`](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations), [`<<`](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#shifting-operations), and [`0xFF`](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#integer-and-long-integer-literals).

Comment: The code works, I've tested this ：) I got this from an open source project.

Comment: @user469652, this method only works if it is supposed to be the case that green and blue's output values are always 0xAA. The result of `(name_hash << 0xFF) & 0xFF` is always 0.  The result of `(name_hash << 0xFFFF) & 0xFF` is always 0.  If this were the intention you could equivalently say `def color(self): return 'rgb(%d,170,170)' % ((hash(self.name) & 0xFF) / 3 + 0xAA)`.  I doubt that's the intention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code is trying to convert a hash value to a color; parts of the computation are buggy.  It takes the lowest 24 bits of `name_hash`, splits them into 3 bytes, makes those colors lighter, and then outputs that as a string.  Going through the sections:

```
red = name_hash & 0xFF
```

Gets the least significant 8 bits of `name_hash` (the `&` operation is bitwise AND, and `0xFF` selects the lowest 8 bits).  The lines for `green` and `blue` are buggy; they should be:

```
green = (name_hash >> 8) & 0xFF
blue = (name_hash >> 16) & 0xFF
```

to get the middle and high blocks of 8 bits each from `name_hash`.  The `make_light_color` function does what the name says: it changes a color value from 0 to 255 into one from 170 to 255 (170 is 2/3 of the way from 0 to 255) to make it represent a lighter color.  Finally, the last line converts the values of the three separate variables into a string.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you find this code?

- `&` is the binary `AND` operation, ANDing with `0xFF` would result in all the bits in your character which are 1 for the 2 byte word.
- `<<` is the left shift operation, which would move the bits towards left and append 0's to the right.
- The `0xAA` seems to be some operation to perform a color transition, that is modify the bit values to make the color light.